# Connecting Database to Eclipse

Tags: java, database, eclipse

I'm trying to create an application in Java which uses oracle database to store information. I'm using Eclipse and I connected the database to Eclipse. I can now see the Database connection in Data Source Explorer. Now how can i use a table in the database in my application ? Can you provide a link to a tutorial ?

Comment: Google "JDBC tutorial"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! However, questions asking us to recommend or find a tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

See examples of [Data Tools Platform usage](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DTP_FAQ)

First, you make a connection:

```
 IConnectionProfile profile = ProfileManager.getInstance().getProfileByName("myprofile");
  IStatus status = profile.connect();
  if (status.getCode() == IStatus.OK)) {
     // success
  } else {
     // failure :(
     if (status.getException() != null) {
        status.getException().printStackTrace();
     }
  }
```

Then, get JDBC connection using managed pool:

```
  public java.sql.Connection getJavaConnectionForProfile (IConnectionProfile profile) {
     IManagedConnection managedConnection = ((IConnectionProfile)profile).
        getManagedConnection ("java.sql.Connection");
     if (managedConnection != null) {
        return (java.sql.Connection) managedConnection.getConnection().getRawConnection();
     }
     return null;
  }
```

This code will, of course access connection profiles stored in your Eclipse-based application and won't see a thing defined in your IDE. Make sure, that you don't mix up your IDE and application.